# Golang `regexp`: Splitting a string with syllables `CV(N)(C)`

Tags: regex, go, regex-greedy

I am trying to split strings with that contain multiple forms like `CV(N)(C)`, where

```go
C = ptk
V = aeiou
N = mn
```

and elements in parentheses are optional, similar to regex `?`.

My initial thought that, in regex form, this is

```go
[ptk][aeiou][mn]?[ptk]?
```

So, for example, these words match, with how they're supposed to be "syllabized" (appear as separate elements in the output) on the right:

```go
ta        => ta
tan       => tan
tank      => tank
tapa      => ta.pa
tanpa     => tan.pa
tankpa    => tank.pa
tapam     => ta.pam
tanpam    => tan.pam
tankpam   => tank.pam
tapamt    => ta.pamt
tanpamt   => tan.pamt
tankpamt  => tank.pamt
tapitetot => ta.pi.te.tot
```

Here is my code below:

```go
package main
import ("strings";"regexp";"fmt")
func main() {
    words := []string{"ta","tan","tank","tapa","tanpa","tankpa","tapam","tanpam","tankpam","tapamt","tanpamt","tankpamt","tapitetot"}
    expected := []string{"ta","tan","tank","ta.pa","tan.pa","tank.pa","ta.pam","tan.pam","tank.pam","ta.pamt","tan.pamt","tank.pamt","ta.pi.te.tot"}

    C := "[ptk]"
    V := "[aeiou]"
    N := "[mn]"
    cvnc := regexp.MustCompile(fmt.Sprintf("(%s)(%s)(%s)?(%s)?", C, V, N, C))
    fmt.Println(cvnc)

    for i := range words {
        fmt.Println(words[i], "\n    expect", strings.Split(expected[i], "."), "\n    got   ", cvnc.FindAllString(words[i], -1))
    }
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVLNSsQwEAZvzVOEgNBAN-BNFBFZ8OYiLOxl3UPppiW0-aGdqrDsk3hZBF_Kp3HSNO162kIm32T-vs7M13dlT6efHsrF7e8VuLyo80pSnStDlHa2BZqyDlplqo7ds1ZW8tMhKDUwTsreFINvyumBJB-23Xf07oFudyHkwCBnGQoTZD1cbnyLdz0Cl-to0JNFRxNMNpiNAToFEiywI0mQnSxA7i-zELH8BOqIxERgRvUExUzhDNYzFk4JkCIwIsnSc2FbB_WOkWQTtFwq23t9FXRtvFK8Yz9RD20WL30HS6udamSKDRdrh78DZcrS647H8zgIltFlRjcZXSHgnCTe_9W7Nyb1aTkyKW1L1ZA_NzjkMC6c2z_n4XWrdhllb4biF1qKBcY1QBqNgjR2OrgKxqeAygJKDPB1xbMy-6emWQ_BZ9kXN57mkRzD8o07GHfxDw)

As is, it will not syllabize the multi-syllabic test cases correctly. For example `tanpa` yields `tanp` (1 element), rather than the expected `tan.pa` (2 elements), and `tapitetot` gives `tap.tet` rather than `ta.pi.te.tot`.

**How can I modify my regex so that it can syllabize these kinds of strings correctly?**

If the problem statement is not clear, the problem is the `(N)(C)` portion of the syllable structure above; the regex greedily consumes the `C` if no `N` is found, disregarding if that `C` is part of another syllable. Is there a way to implement this check?

Comment: Hi @bigyihsuan. I think I see my answer is wrong now. I will delete it and try to think how to help you in the comment of your question

Comment: I did check at https://regex101.com/ and your regex [ptk][aeiou][mn]?[ptk]? will return "tanp" for your string "tanpa". That's language independent. Do you think that we should change the regex?

Comment: @TranvuXuannhat Yes. I want to find a regex that will perform the behavior mentioned in the original post.